# unit test for click event native element (anchor tag)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have simple anchor tag with some url. The goal of the test is when click on the link it should be open in new tab and then compare given url to opened new tab url.

I have tried with spyOn with window object. But i am not succeed.

Here is what i have tried.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">google</a>


import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('guideline link', () => {
    let comp: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('link should be opened in separate tab', async () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        spyOn(window, 'open');
        const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('a');
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(link).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.google.com/');
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You are not clicking the `anchor` tag in your code. Then how will that redirect?

Comment: what if i make `const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('a').click();`

Comment: nobody have answered this question? I am interested too

Answer (score 6):

Faced similar issue. 
This worked for me:

```
  const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("a");
  link.click();
```